# Format syntax when adding values

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to add several values of a tuple together using format(). I wrote a function that returns a tuple with 12 values.

My tuple looks like this:

`In[86]results
Out[86]: (15.24, 2527.4, 2812.59, 7.87, 2389.72, 1795.39, 594.33, 98.34, 68.84, 60.0, 132, 5)`

I have been printing to stdout like this (based on [format examples from docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)):

`print('-Sponge Yeast: {0[0]}g'.format(results))`

`print('-Sponge Flour: {0[1]}g'.format(results))`

`print('-Sponge Water: {0[2]}g'.format(results))`

I want to print another line that is the sum of the first 3 values in results.

In the past, I could do it like this:

`print('-Total Sponge Weight: {:n}g'.format(a+b+c))`
where a, b, c...,i equal the 12 values respectively.

Instead of creating 12 variables for the 12 values of the tuple, I want to use a single variable for the tuple. But, **how can I sum several values in the tuple and use the format()?** I've tried:

`print('-Total Sponge Weight: {0[0] + 0[1] + 0[2]}g'.format(results))`

`print('-Total Sponge Weight: {:n}g'.format(0.results + 1.results + 2.results))`

But this does not work. I do know I can simply have my function output the correct value, and I can refer to it as {0[xx]}. Just wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3's f-Strings, this is easy.

`values = (1, 2, 3)`

`In[1]: f'The sum of values is {values[0]+values[1]+values[2]}!`

`Out[1]: 'The sum of values is 6!`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [pprint](https://devdocs.io/python~3.7/library/pprint). I've never used it myself, but it is designed for formatted printing of data.